# TextView not displaying all the lines?

Tags: java, android, textview

This is the XML layout for the TextView:

```
<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/scrollview1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:fillViewport="true">
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:textSize="17sp" 
        />
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The text is being sourced from a .txt file containing 431 lines. But the first 81 lines are out of the screen ( off the top edge of the screen). What am I doing wrong?

The code reading the .txt file:

```
    String l="";
    TextView two=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    InputStream is =getAssets().open("codes1.txt");
    InputStreamReader iz=new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader bis = new BufferedReader(iz);
    try {
        String text="";
        while((l=bis.readLine())!=null) {
            text=text+l+"\n";
        }
        two.setText(text);
        two.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    } catch(Exception a) { Log.d("error is "+a.toString(),"error"); }
```

Comment: Does the view scroll?

Comment: so what happens when you scroll it up? do you see the first 81 lines?

Comment: @EmilAdz No, it hits its upper limit. It only scrolls down from the 81st line.

Comment: are you positive that those 81 appear in the file and do get copied into the "text" string?

Comment: @EmilAdz Yes, I printed the String `text` in the LogCat, it shows all the lines including the first 81..

Comment: Ok, so the content is there, try to remove "android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left" from the TextView and remove this line two.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());.

Comment: i think setting top padding should work

Comment: @EmilAdz Worked perfectly :). Write as answer for points.

Comment: @vergilcorleone, comment added as an answer : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the content is there, try to remove `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"` from the `TextView` and remove this line

`two.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());` from your java file.